# how to use length-limit on RegExp Object with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const ipv6="([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+)";
const regex = new RegExp(ipv6);
const result = SAMPLE_STRING.match(regex);
console.log(result);
```

run code result is

```js
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+):([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}+)/: Nothing to repeat
```

The 'ipv6' works with a regex-compiler, but not with javascript.

And i must use the 'new Regex' object.
how can i make the work?

Comment: See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZRsHQ6/1) it tells you why your regex is invalid

Comment: Thanks @Reyno! My flavor was wrong on regex-compiler XD